# How to convert this file to XML?

Tags: php, xml, symfony, yaml

How can I convert this file to XML ?

```
services:
IHQS.nuitblanche.admin.news:
class: IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Admin\NewsAdmin
tags:
- { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: nuitblanche, label: News }
arguments: [null, IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Entity\News, IHQSNuitBlancheBundle:NewsAdmin]
```

Especially for the tags part

Is :

```
<service id="nb.admin.news" class="IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Admin\NewsAdmin">
            <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="NuitBlanche" label="News" />
            <argument />
            <argument>IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Entity\News</argument>
            <argument>IHQSNuitBlancheBundle:Admin</argument>
</service>
```

Correct or?

Comment: Have you seen [How to convert symfony yaml config files to xml format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942272/how-to-convert-symfony-yaml-config-files-to-xml-format)? And can't you say it's correct or not by testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert it, you can just create the XML file and include your YAML file:

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony-project.org/2.0/container">
  <imports>
    <import resource="default.yml" class="sfServiceContainerLoaderFileYaml" />
  </imports>
</container>
```

This should also get you started to then override the settings so you can easily transpose your YAML into XML:

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony-project.org/2.0/container">
  <imports>
    <import resource="default.xml" />
  </imports>
  <parameters>
    <!-- These parameters override the one defined in default.xml -->
  </parameters>
  <services>
    <!-- These service definitions override the one defined in default.xml -->
  </services>
</container>
```

This is part of the blog post series, namely:

- [Symfony Service Container: Using XML or YAML to describe Services](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/15/symfony-service-container-using-xml-or-yaml-to-describe-services)

The component itself is documented here:

- [Service Container (current version)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Using a similar example XML for some example YAML:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    my_mailer:
        class:        Acme\HelloBundle\Mailer
        arguments:    [sendmail]
```

In XML:

```
<!-- app/config/config.xml -->
<services>
    <service id="my_mailer" class="Acme\HelloBundle\Mailer">
        <argument>sendmail</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

With some help from str_replace or preg_replace you should be able to break your input text into (multidimensional) array which would be much easier to convert to XML

```
$example => array(
    'services' => array(
        'IHQS.nuitblanche.admin.news' => array(
            'class' => 'IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Admin\NewsAdmin',
            'tags' => array(
                'name' => 'sonata.admin',
                'manager_type' => 'orm',
                'group' => 'nuitblanche',
                'label' => 'News'
            ),
            arguments => array(
                null,
                'IHQS\NuitBlancheBundle\Entity\News',
                'IHQSNuitBlancheBundle:NewsAdmin'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but now what should i do with that? Should i use a tool that will convert it for me or do it by myself?